# How to select and deselect multiple check box with a button click in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project, i have multiple check box (total 27).I am trying to select all the check box with a single button click and  i am able to do it.But i want to deselect the same check box with the same button click.So the button should act like a selector and a de-selector.I can not use a check box instead of the button.
My html code is:

```
<div class="countryAll">
    <span class="countrySelect_lngTrans_Translatable" title="Select All">
                <input type="button" class="selectAllcountry" />
            </span>
    <span class="displayData">Select whole country</span>
</div>
```

In js:

```
$(self.element).on('click', '.selectAllcountry', function(e) {
    debugger;
    $('.chkCountry').trigger('click')
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: There isn't any check-box in provided markup...

Comment: `$('button.selectAllcountry').on('click', function(){ $('.countryAll').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true) })`

Comment: something like https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L98ros97/1/?

Comment: I tried with the code you have provided in the jsfiddle, but its not working for me. @Arun P Johny   @ Rayon Dabre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `trigger` will always toggle the state, so if some elements are checked and some aren't then it won't work fine.

Instead you can try something like

```js
$(document).on('click', '.selectAllcountry', function(e) {
  var $checks = $('.chkCountry');
  $checks.prop('checked', !$checks.is(':checked'))

  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countryAll">
  <span class="countrySelect_lngTrans_Translatable" title="Select       All">
                <input type="button" class="selectAllcountry" />
            </span>
  <span class="displayData">Select whole country</span>
</div>
<input class="chkCountry" type="checkbox" />
<input class="chkCountry" type="checkbox" />
<input class="chkCountry" type="checkbox" />
<input class="chkCountry" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Its not working.     var $checks = $('.chkCountry');   the value of $checks shows undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $('.selectAllcountry').on('click', function(){  
     if ($('.selectAllcountry').is(':checked')) {     
         $('.chkCountry').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true); 
     } else {
         $('.chkCountry').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false); 
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
    $(document).on('click', 'input.selectAllcountry', function(e) {
        if ($('input.selectAllcountry').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('.chkCountry').prop('checked',true);
    }
    else
    $('.chkCountry').prop('checked',false);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var chkStatus = true;
$('.selectAllcountry').click(function() {
  $('.countryAll').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', chkStatus);
  chkStatus = !chkStatus;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countryAll">
  <span class="countrySelect_lngTrans_Translatable" title="Select All">
                <input type="button" class="selectAllcountry" />
            </span>
  <span class="displayData">Select whole country</span>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

as you have done the portion of selection, now focus on Deselecting.
to remove all checkbox inputs at once

```
 $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

or you can add class as identifier and then remove checked element on the basis of class.
for exa.

```
$('.chkCountry').removeAttr('checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have made one mistake in your code you have used class attribute twise in html tag.I think that's why it take first class attribute and other are ignored.

`<div class="countryAll">
    <span class="countrySelect_lngTrans_Translatable" title="Select All">
                <input type="button" class="selectAllcountry" />
            </span>
    <span class="displayData">Select whole country</span>
</div>`

please combine all class in single class attribute.
I think it will be helpful.